# Scale div proportionally to fit viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a small function that proportionally reduces the size of a `div` until it's height is the same as the viewport. This works perfectly. I have 2 issues I'd like to fix

1. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?
2. Once the height of the viewport is reduced it doesn't scale back up when the viewport is increased.

The objective behind the function is so that the `container` div is never higher than the viewport. This needs to be controlled by setting the `width` of the `container` as it contents are responsive. I've used a simple image with a width of 100% for demonstration purposes. I haven't used `vh` or `vw` due to lack of browser support. I need to support IE8.

[Demo Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbL205nx/)

```
function setImageViewPointHeight() {

  // get current viewport height
  var targetHeight = $(window).height();

  // get current container height
  var containerHeight = $('.container').height();

  // get current container width
  var containerWidth = $('.container').width();


  // only set width if container is higher than viewport
  if (containerHeight > targetHeight) {

    // keep reducing container height/width value by 0.1% until target is reached
    while (containerHeight > targetHeight) {
      containerHeight = containerHeight - (containerHeight * .01);
      containerWidth = containerWidth - (containerWidth * .01);
    }

    // now we have desired calculated width
    $('.container').width(containerWidth + 'px');
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you live with this browser support? http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Comment: @lipp I'd like to keep IE8 if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account browser support I don't see a problem with this approach. It seems clean enough from my perspective.

To fix your issue of container height adjustment when the viewport height is reduced simply set the `width` to `initial` when the function is invoked.

```
function setImageViewPointHeight() {

  $('.container').css('width', 'initial');   <-- add this

  var targetHeight = $(window).height();
  var containerHeight = $('.container').height();
  var containerWidth = $('.container').width();

  if (containerHeight > targetHeight) {
    while (containerHeight > targetHeight) {
      containerHeight = containerHeight - (containerHeight * .01);
      containerWidth = containerWidth - (containerWidth * .01);
    }
    $('.container').width(containerWidth + 'px');
  }

}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbL205nx/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `vw` `vh` CSS units to scale the div to the viewport.

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

IE8 doesn't support it, but you can find polyfills for it
https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately due to browser support this approach would be clunkier than my current implementation. I've updated my question highlighting my need for IE8 support.

Comment: That's why I suggested polyfills :)

Comment: vmin should probably be the unit of choice as it ensures that the sized element will not get too large in either direction.

Comment: In 2021, this should no longer be an issue
See: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=vh)